# format and crop with ghostscript

Tags: crop, ghostscript

Good morning,

My customer sends me the label + instructions for use. I would like to keep only the shipping label and switch to a 10x15 format to edit it on my zebra. how to do it with ghostscript. THANKS

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZgEA.png)

I added the parameters dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=100 -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=150 and -dUseCropBox to my old ghostscript parameters.

```
            if QuelEditeurPdf == "GS" then
                local paramGS = ' -dPrinted -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q - 
                dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=100 -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=150 -  dUseCropBox -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 
                -sPAPERSIZE=' .. Size .. '-dNumCopies=' .. nbCopies
            if ScriptFileExists(cheminPdf) then
                local cmd = gswin64 .. paramGS .. ' -sOutputFile="%printer%' .. 
                imprimante .. '" "' .. cheminPdf .. '"'
                local f, err = io.popen(cmd)`
```

Comment: Since you haven't supplied an example PDF file (just a picture of one) and you haven't given the dimensions an exact answer is not possible. However, in broad; You don't want to set -dUseCropBox. You need to set the media size to the size you want (as you;ve done with DEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS etc) and then you need to move the content of the PDF file on the output media so that the part you want lies under the 'window' you have defined. To do that you need to use the PostScript translate operator to move the origin (bottom left = 0,0) so that the correct portion is drawn.

Comment: Oh and you can't just use the mswinpr2 device either. You'll have to create a new PDF file first using the pdfwrite device, then print that separately using mswinpr2.